# Show final shipping cost on custom block page magento

Tags: magento-1.7, php, shipping

I am at wits end end with this problem. I have a design that I need to add the checkout info on a custom magento page right sidebar (wired) I already have the PHP code that pulls the grand total and the sub total. I need the full shipping cost to show up like this:

[image: Checkout info on custom block page sidebar]

If anyone can also give me the code to show the Promo code values that would be killing 3 birds with 1 pebble stone.!

Thanks.

Comment: what code do you already have for the other items?

Answer (score 1):

```
$quote()->getShippingAddress()->getGroupedAllShippingRates();
```